# Time for a particle undergoing brownian motion to reach a point in a volume

Tags: diffusion, brownian-motion

I was wondering how one could calculate the average time a particle needs to reach a random point in a small sphere (filled by water) with a radius of maybe $10 \mu m$. I thought of using the [Stokes-Einstein-Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_relation_(kinetic_theory)), but then I just get a diffusion coefficient with the unit [m²/s]. Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Just to make sure I got this right: Your domain is a sphere, which the particle cannot escape. You want to compute the average time it takes to diffuse to a point inside the sphere. I imagine that this point can't really be a point; rather it must have some finite volume. I think you won't get an analytical solution unless the point is at the center of the sphere as it would break the symmetry. Numerically the most straightforward way would be to do a Monte Carlo simulation. You might also consider solving the PDE (reflecting BCs for the sphere, absorbing at the point).

Comment: You understood it correctly. There is no escape and the point can be seen as a volume (~175 nm³), which can be calculated easily. However, I really don't want to make a simulation. I just want to have a approximation for an average time frame. Not necessary to make it 100% correct. Mainly because I am not interested in the best way to calculate or solve this particular question, but more in the follow up calculations.

Comment: For a "back of the envelope" type calculation.  First you should get a mean free path (mfp) from the diffusion equations.  This gives you the average length of one scattering event.  Then, if the total length to travel is then (L) which is assumed bigger than the mfp you will need on average ~(L/mfp)^2 scattering events.  then given the average velocity you can calculate the time between events.  (I think this is correct.)

Comment: All mean free path equations are not so great. They assume, that all the particles are of the same type, which is never the case. In my case, I have two big particle in water, so the MFP will assume just the interaction with water particles. But anyway, let's assume the MFP 0.1 nm. Now I would get (10000 / 10)² scattering events. But the velocity of the scattering event should be only dependent on the viscosity and temperature (at least I think so). However, from the Einstein-Stokes-Equation I don't get the velocity of the scattering event. Do you know how to calculate it?

Comment: @dgrat, (if you flag my name with a @, I get a mail message ... otherwise I may never come back to your question.)  With different types of particles you can still get scattering cross sections.  (usually it's the big particle that is important... maybe you know that already.)  If there are numerous particles then you have to make some smart guess/ average.  Re: velocity.  Well that mostly depends on the smaller particle it's mass and the temperature.  Though everything gets complicated and it's best to measure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remark, the average hitting time is finite because the volume is finite. None of what I write would make sense in an infinite system.

Let us consider that the target is a ball of radius $a$ at the center of the sphere and let us call $T(\vec r)$ the average hitting time for a Brownian particle starting at position $\vec r$ from the origin. $T(\vec r)$ depends only on $r=\|\vec r\|$. Consider now a Brownian motion $\vec B$ during a short time $\mathrm dt$ and compute the variation of the hitting time 
$$\mathrm dt=T(\vec r)-T(\vec r+\vec B_{\mathrm dt}).$$
Use the Taylor expansion in spherical coordinates of the right-hand side
$$\mathrm dt=-\vec\nabla T(\vec r)\cdot\vec B_{\mathrm dt}-\frac12\vec B_{\mathrm dt}\cdot H_T(\vec r)\cdot \vec B_{\mathrm dt}$$
where $H_T$ is the Hessian matrix of $T$ which contains only one non-zero element equal to $\frac1{r^2}\partial_r(r^2\partial_r T(r))$ on the diagonal. Taking the average over all realisations of the Brownian motion, one gets
$$\mathrm dt=-\frac12\frac1{r^2}\partial_r\left(r^2\partial_r T(r)\right) \; 2D\mathrm dt,$$ or in a simpler form, with $\Delta_r$ denoting the spherical Laplacian,
$$D\Delta_r T(r)=-1.\tag{1}$$
This form is quite general for the average hitting time. It is actually the Fokker-Planck equation in which we have replaced the time derivative by $-1$.

Let us solve (1). We have $$T(r)=-\frac{r^2}{6D}+\frac{A}r+B.$$
$A$ and $B$ are constants. We must have $T(a)=0$. The second condition depends on the boundary at $r=R$. Let us consider that the boudary is reflecting, so the particles bounce on the sphere and continue to diffuse inside. This is a von Neumann boundary condition, that translates mathematically into $\left.\partial_rT(r)\right\rvert_{r=R}=0$. This defines $A=-R^3/3D$. With $T(a)=0$ we find
$B=a^2/6D+R^3/3Da$. 
Finally 
$$T(r)=\frac{a^2-r^2}{6D}+\frac{R^3}{3D}\left(\frac1a-\frac1r\right).$$

If the starting point is uniformally distributed inside the sphere of radius $R$, the average is 
$$ \int_a^R\frac{3r^2}{R^3-a^3}T(r)\mathrm dr=\frac{(R-a)^2}{15Da}\frac{5R^3+6 R^2a + 3 Ra^2 + a^3}{R^2+Ra+a^2}.$$

Therefore, for $a\ll R$ we get $$\left\langle T\right\rangle\approx\frac{R^3}{3Da}.$$ 
The average hitting time scales like $R^3$, so is actually proportional to the *volume* and inversely proportional to the *radius* of the target.

Answer (score 0):

Note that a particle can pass through a particular location many many time, what you are looking for is the [first passage time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-hitting-time_model), FPT $F(r',t|r)$, which is the probability of taking time $t$ to move from point $r$ to point $r'$. The quantity you are looking for is the mean FPT, given
$$ \langle T \rangle = \int_0^\infty t F(r',t|r) dt $$
In general free space (particular $d\ge3$), this mean time may can be infinite because the particle may never pass a point. For confined dominate, it will eventually does, which means that $\langle T \rangle$ is finite.

In confined domain, the qualitative result should depend on the distance of $r,r'$ from the spherical wall as well as distance $|r-r'|$. I don't think there is any simple solution.

For your reaction type system, it may be easier to just do the particle simulation and calculate $\langle T \rangle$. Alternatively, the calculation of $\langle T \rangle$ in random walk problem is equivalent to solving diffusion equation with an absorbing boundary condition, or a sink at $r'$. The total probability will decrease over time and the FPT is simply the $F(r',t) = \partial_t \int dr P(r,t)$. This can be done on existing software to solve diffusion equation, so you can see the result quickly.

---

Mathematically, the FPT is related with the solution (or Green function) $P(r',t|r)$ of the diffusion equation (subjected to the boundary condition with diffusion constant $D$) as follow:
$$ P(r',t|r) = \int_0^\infty F(r',t'|r) P(r',t-t'|r') dt'$$
The relationship is clear as the walker need to go to spend $t'$ to go to the point $r'$ first and then take another $t-t'$ to loop back. Once $P$ is known, the $F$ can be calculated by Laplace transform and so does $\langle T \rangle$.

Comment: As the OP was happy with an approximate solution: I think one should be able to solve this analytically in rectangular coordinates (cube instead of a sphere for both the entire domain and the volume enclosing the absorbing point). Yes? No?

Comment: @alarge Exact solution might be possible for special configuration, say the sink in the middle, I think. However, in general, the exact shape boundary is not quite important. It is usually solved by approximation. With a quick search, the closest results are 2D, but not 3D http://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.83.021919

Comment: So far I use the Stokes-Einstein equation and the Einstein-Smoluchowski equation. r²=6*D*t. But I am not sure, whether this equation is correct/appropriate to calculate the average time to reach a certain point. However, D is easy to calculate from the Stokes equation and it would be great if this approach is correct to get an impression of the time scale.